# Is it possible to add html-attributes without values in rails link_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to output an a-tag like this:

```
<a href="#" itemscope class="features__cta button>Stuff</a>
```

I know I can add html-attributes like this to the tag, but how do I add one without a value to it?

```
<%= link_to t('features.cta'), t('features.cta_link') , class:
'features__cta button',  itemprop: "priceSpecification" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Boolean attributes](http://w3c.github.io/html/infrastructure.html#sec-boolean-attributes)

Without value or with nil string value is still equivalent, So you can write like this

```
<%= link_to t('features.cta'), t('features.cta_link') , class:
'features__cta button',  itemprop: '' %>
```

Comment: this will result in itemprop="" in the markup, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can add HTML attributes like this

```
<%= link_to t('features.cta'), t('features.cta_link') , :class => "Myclass", :itemprop => ""%>
```